# How can I use / run / execute other composer.json file which is placed inside component? I need it when I install my Joomla component in Joomla-site

Tags: php, joomla, components, composer-php

I have created component for Joomla 2.5.11. And now I have to use composer during installation my component. I am using AWS libraries, that is why I need to upload AWS PHP libraries to target Joomla Web Site. How can I do it?

I guess to execute autoloader for downloading libraries.

Comment: Can't you just add what you need to the site's composer.json?

Comment: My aim is to make my component fully automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can move on the directory where the composer.json of aws-sdk is and run composer install.

Comment: I think that i need to clarify my question. Component has to be FULLY automatic: We choose the ZIP file with component - click upload and libraries from AWS must be uploaded from Amazon...